# Baking a NavMesh Puts Walkable Space on the top of an Obstacle

Tags: unity-game-engine, navmesh

I am working on a game using a NavMesh system. I place obstacles and in the Navigation tab, mark them as static. The floor and walls are also static. Then I bake the Nav Mesh. However, it builds a NavMesh on top of the obstacle, as well as inside.

The only components attached to the cube are Transform, Cube Mesh Filter, Box Collider, Mesh Renderer, and Material.

[image: I don't know why]

Comment: This is completely normal behavior.  The space on top of your obstacle is considered walk able space.  However, you do not have to worry about your agents using that space if you don't want them to, as you have not set up a link between the floor and the top of the obstacle.

Comment: @JamesHogle It places Walkable space inside the object as well, I tested it using a point and click movement system, and the player pretended that everywhere was walkable space. Sorry but I am very inexperienced with NavMeshes.

Answer (score 2):

Old thread but since I had the same problem and ended up here (and in case I forget and end up here again):

Simply add a NavMeshModifier component to the obstacle.  Then, make sure Override Area Type is checked, and set the Area Type to "Not Walkable".

Rebake your NavMesh - done.